# Error when running <petalinux-build -s> in <Zynq UltraScale+ MPSoC Base TRD 2019.1 - Design Module 5>

Tags: xilinx

If I run <petalinux-build -s> in <Zynq UltraScale+ MPSoC Base TRD 2019.1 - Design Module 5>, I get the error message below:

```
WARNING: nativesdk-glibc-initial-2.28-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git;branch=release/2.28/master;name=glibc, attempting MIRRORS if available

WARNING: binutils-crosssdk-x86_64-petalinux-linux-2.31-r0 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git;branch=binutils-2_31-branch;protocol=git, attempting MIRRORS if available

ERROR: nativesdk-glibc-initial-2.28-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-P8eDdA2gUC"; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh"; export GIT_SSL_CAINFO="/opt/petalinux/components/yocto/source/aarch64/buildtools/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"; export PATH="/home/xim/xim/rdf0421-zcu102-base-trd-2019-1/petalinux/bsp/build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-petalinux-linux/nativesdk-glibc-initial/2.28-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-petalinux-linux.gcc-crosssdk-initial-x86_64-petalinux-linux:/home/xim/xim/rdf0421-zcu102-base-trd-2019-1/petalinux/bsp/build/tmp/sysroots-uninative/x86_64-linux/usr/bin:/home/xim/xim/rdf0421-zcu102-base-trd-2019-1/petalinux/bsp/build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-petalinux-linux/nativesdk-glibc-initial/2.28-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/chrpath-native:/opt/petalinux/components/yocto/source/aarch64/layers/core/scripts:/home/xim/xim/rdf0421-zcu102-base-trd-2019-1/petalinux/bsp/build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-petalinux-linux/nativesdk-glibc-initial/2.28-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/x86_64-petalinux-linux:/home/xim/xim/rdf0421-zcu102-base-trd-2019-1/petalinux/bsp/build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-petalinux-linux/nativesdk-glibc-initial/2.28-r0/recipe-sysroot/opt/petalinux/2019.1/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/bin/crossscripts:/home/xim/xim/rdf0421-zcu102-base-trd-2019-1/petalinux/bsp/build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-petalinux-linux/nativesdk-glibc-initial/2.28-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/home/xim/xim/rdf0421-zcu102-base-trd-2019-1/petalinux/bsp/build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-petalinux-linux/nativesdk-glibc-initial/2.28-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/home/xim/xim/rdf0421-zcu102-base-trd-2019-1/petalinux/bsp/build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-petalinux-linux/nativesdk-glibc-initial/2.28-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/home/xim/xim/rdf0421-zcu102-base-trd-2019-1/petalinux/bsp/build/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-petalinux-linux/nativesdk-glibc-initial/2.28-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/opt/petalinux/tools/xsct/bin:/opt/petalinux/tools/xsct/gnu/microblaze/lin/bin:/opt/petalinux/tools/xsct/gnu/aarch32/lin/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin:/opt/petalinux/tools/xsct/gnu/armr5/lin/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin:/opt/petalinux/tools/xsct/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-none/bin:/opt/petalinux/components/yocto/source/aarch64/layers/core/bitbake/bin:/home/xim/xim/rdf0421-zcu102-base-trd-2019-1/petalinux/bsp/build/tmp/hosttools"; export HOME="/home/xim"; LANG=C git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 clone --bare --mirror git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git /home/xim/xim/rdf0421-zcu102-base-trd-2019-1/petalinux/bsp/build/downloads/git2/sourceware.org.git.glibc.git --progress failed with exit code 128, 

output:

Cloning into bare repository '/home/xim/xim/rdf0421-zcu102-base-trd-2019-1/petalinux/bsp/build/downloads/git2/sourceware.org.git.glibc.git'...
fatal: Unable to look up sourceware.org (port 9418) (Temporary failure in name resolution)
```

Comment: @Werner Editing is correct, flagging isn't for these.

Comment: Alright. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you don't have Internet access.
If so, don't worry Yocto has good solutions for this.
Check:

- [PREMIRRORS](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-PREMIRRORS)
- [BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-BB_GENERATE_MIRROR_TARBALLS)

Or how [to work behind a network proxy](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Working_Behind_a_Network_Proxy)